# PnP PowerShell: Bad Request when attempting to create a PnPAzureAD App

Tags: c#, sharepoint, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, pnp.powershell

When running the following command on PowerShell 7.2: `Register-PnPAzureADApp -ApplicationName TestApp -Tenant yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com -Store CurrentUser -Username "yourname@domain.com" -Password (Read-Host -AsSecureString -Prompt "Enter Password")`

A bad request error is returned on execution:
`Register-PnPAzureADApp: {"error":{"code":"Request_BadRequest","message":"A null value was found with the expected type 'Edm.String[Nullable=False]'. The expected type 'Edm.String[Nullable=False]' does not allow null values.","innerError":{"date":"2023-07-31T14:21:28","request-id":"7dbf66db-f159-45dc-b061-7a1dcdc9e323","client-request-id":"7dbf66db-f159-45dc-b061-7a1dcdc9e323"}}}`

Does anybody have some insight as to what might be the issue with the command? I am unsure if it is an issue with my environment or some other factor. Any help is appreciated! :)

Following [Azure AD App Only Authentication in SharePoint Online using PnP PowerShell](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/certificate-based-authentication-to-connect-to-sharepoint-online-sites/) and expected to have obtained a certificate that I could use in my Azure-Functions application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a wrong build of PnP.PowerShell, installing the nightly build with: `Install-Module PnP.PowerShell -Scope CurrentUser -AllowPrerelease -SkipPublisherCheck` Did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

The error you encountered while running the `Register-PnPAzureADApp` cmdlet indicates that there might be an issue with the parameters being passed to the cmdlet. The error message specifically mentions that a null value was found with an expected type that does not allow null values.

I tried the same command in my environment, and it created the `application` successfully.

```
  Register-PnPAzureADApp -ApplicationName TestApp1 -Tenant abc..com -Store CurrentUser -Username "Abc..com" -Password (Read-Host -AsSecureString -Prompt "Enter Password")
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

If you are still facing the issue with the above command, try the below commands to create an `AzureAD` application

**Method 1:**

Try with `App-Only authentication`: Instead of using the `-Username` and `-Password` parameters for user-based authentication, you can try using app-only authentication with Interactive mode.

```
Register-PnPAzureADApp -ApplicationName SPSitesSelected -Tenant abc.com -Store CurrentUser -SharePointApplicationPermissions "Sites.Selected" -Interactive
```

**Method 2:**

Try with `App-Only Authentication`: Instead of using the `-Username` and `-Password` parameters for user-based authentication, you can try using app-only authentication with a certificate.

```
Register-PnPAzureADApp -ApplicationName TestApp -Tenant abc.com -CertificatePath c:\certificate.pfx -CertificatePassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -String "password" -AsPlainText -Force) -Username "yourname@domain.com" -Password (Read-Host -AsSecureString -Prompt "Enter password")
```

Reference: [Register-PnPAzureADApp](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Register-PnPAzureADApp.html)

Comment: I attempted both of these methods, creating both a Self-Signed Certificate and using the interactive mode, and both methods returned with the same result. I wish there was a way to know what value is tripping this error.

Comment: Try with Azure PowerShell, if still facing issue with Local PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

In case it's useful for anyone, I had the same error when running this in the "new" PowerShell (7.4.1) against PnP.PowerShell 2.2.0. However, it worked on the same machine via "old" PowerShell (5.1.19041.4046) against PnP.PowerShell 1.11.0.